# Using BeautifulSoup to find a HTML tag that contains certain text

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, html-content-extraction

I'm trying to get the elements in an HTML doc that contain the following pattern of text: #\S{11}

```
<h2> this is cool #12345678901 </h2>
```

So, the previous would match by using:

```
soup('h2',text=re.compile(r' #\S{11}'))
```

And the results would be something like:

```
[u'blahblah #223409823523', u'thisisinteresting #293845023984']
```

I'm able to get all the text that matches (see line above). But I want the parent element of the text to match, so I can use that as a starting point for traversing the document tree. In this case, I'd want all the h2 elements to return, not the text matches.

Ideas?

Comment: Actually, the h2 restriction is ignored according to the BeautifulSoup documentation: "If you use text, then any values you give for name and the keyword arguments are ignored."

Comment: @Rabarberski Not sure what the situation was in 2010, but [by 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120427003845/http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) finds that use `text` (or `string` which replaced it) would not ignore any other restrictions

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_text = """
<h2>this is cool #12345678901</h2>
<h2>this is nothing</h2>
<h1>foo #126666678901</h1>
<h2>this is interesting #126666678901</h2>
<h2>this is blah #124445678901</h2>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)


for elem in soup(text=re.compile(r' #\S{11}')):
    print elem.parent
```

Prints:

```
<h2>this is cool #12345678901</h2>
<h2>this is interesting #126666678901</h2>
<h2>this is blah #124445678901</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's confusing that it returned what looked like a list of unicode strings. I appreciate the help.

Comment: `.parent` was awesome! I never thought about it. Thanks @nosklo. +1

Comment: If you want to iterate the output from the search right away, then for is perfect. Else how about a list comprehension as such:
[elem.parent for element in soup(text=re.compile(r' #\S{11}'))]

Comment: @sotangochips Yeah at first it looks like it's returning a plain unicode string, but it's actually a NavigableString with a `.parent`. Had to use PyCharm's debugger to realise it was not a plain string.

Answer (score 24):

BeautifulSoup search operations deliver [a list of] `BeautifulSoup.NavigableString` objects when `text=` is used as a criteria as opposed to `BeautifulSoup.Tag` in other cases. Check the object's `__dict__` to see the attributes made available to you. Of these attributes, `parent` is favored over `previous` because of [changes in BS4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import re

html_text = """
<h2>this is cool #12345678901</h2>
<h2>this is nothing</h2>
<h2>this is interesting #126666678901</h2>
<h2>this is blah #124445678901</h2>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

# Even though the OP was not looking for 'cool', it's more understandable to work with item zero.
pattern = re.compile(r'cool')

pprint(soup.find(text=pattern).__dict__)
#>> {'next': u'\n',
#>>  'nextSibling': None,
#>>  'parent': <h2>this is cool #12345678901</h2>,
#>>  'previous': <h2>this is cool #12345678901</h2>,
#>>  'previousSibling': None}

print soup.find('h2')
#>> <h2>this is cool #12345678901</h2>
print soup.find('h2', text=pattern)
#>> this is cool #12345678901
print soup.find('h2', text=pattern).parent
#>> <h2>this is cool #12345678901</h2>
print soup.find('h2', text=pattern) == soup.find('h2')
#>> False
print soup.find('h2', text=pattern) == soup.find('h2').text
#>> True
print soup.find('h2', text=pattern).parent == soup.find('h2')
#>> True
```

Comment: For me `soup.find('h2', text=pattern)` gives the tag directly, no need to call `.parent`. Also the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) says that you can combine the `string` (`text` in previous versions) parameter with arguments that find tags. In this case BeautifulSoup will return the tag

Answer (score 5):

With bs4 (Beautiful Soup 4), the OP's attempt works exactly like expected:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<h2> this is cool #12345678901 </h2>")
soup('h2',text=re.compile(r' #\S{11}'))
```

returns `[<h2> this is cool #12345678901 </h2>]`.