# Search by tag contents with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to search for a particular tag by it's text contents. For example:

```
<a href="http://goinghere.com">Lets go somewhere</a>
```

I want to find the above by searching for the text 'Lets go somewhere'.
I am currently doing it using re. Can it be done in BeautifulSoup or is it better to use re in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = BeautifulSoup(...)
s.find(text='Lets go somewhere')
```

You can also use regex.

[Using BeautifulSoup to find a HTML tag that contains certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866000/using-beautifulsoup-to-find-a-html-tag-that-contains-certain-text)

*Edit: While the find method prints a string if you use it on the command line, that's actually just a representation of the object it returns; you can access the parent attribute on it to access its BeautifulSoup tag object.*