# How can I emulate ":contains" using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project where I need to a bit of scraping. The project is on Google App Engine, and we're currently using Python 2.5. Ideally, we would use [PyQuery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/) but due to running on App Engine and Python 2.5, this is not an option.

I've seen questions like this one on [finding an HTML tag with certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866000/using-beautifulsoup-to-find-a-html-tag-that-contains-certain-text), but they don't quite hit the mark.

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="description">
        This post is about <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia.org</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- More posts of similar format -->
```

In PyQuery, I could do something like this (as far as I know):

```
s = pq(html)
s(".post:contains('This post is about Wikipedia.org')")
# returns all posts containing that text
```

Naively, I had though that I could do something like this in BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.findAll(True, "post", text=("This post is about Google.com"))
# []
```

However, that yielded no results. I changed my query to use a regular expression, and got a bit further, but still no luck:

```
soup.findAll(True, "post", text=re.compile(".*This post is about.*Google.com.*"))
# []
```

It works if I omit `Google.com`, but then I need to do all the filtering manually. **Is there anyway to emulate `:contains` using BeautifulSoup?**

*Alternatively*, is there some PyQuery-like library that works on App Engine (on Python 2.5)?

Comment: Why don't you migrate to 2.7 where [lxml is available](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/newin27#Supported_Third-Party_Libraries)?

Comment: We definitely want to, we just haven't been able to yet. Old codebase, not enough time, etc. It's a fair criticism.

Comment: Well, the [migration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Considerations_When_Migrating_Your_Application) seems not too complex and as your applications are versioned you can just give it a try and move back if it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We *did* try that. One of our past developers was too clever for his own good, making things considerably more complex :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the BeautifulSoup docs (emphasis mine):

> "text is an argument that lets you search for NavigableString objects
>   *instead of* Tags"

That is to say, your code:

```
soup.findAll(True, "post", text=re.compile(".*This post is about.*Google.com.*"))
```

Is not the same as:

```
regex = re.compile('.*This post is about.*Google.com.*')
[post for post in soup.findAll(True, 'post') if regex.match(post.text)]
```

The reason you have to remove the Google.com is that there's a NavigableString object in the BeautifulSoup tree for `"This post is about"`, and another one for `"Google.com"`, but they're under different elements.

Incidentally, `post.text` exists but is not documented, so I wouldn't rely on that either, I wrote that code by accident! Use some other means of smushing together all the text under `post`.

Comment: I definitely read that quote, but couldn't understand the difference. This is definitely what I needed. Thanks :)

Comment: @NT3RP "couldn't understand the difference": Same for me, the BeautifulSoup documentation is IMO really a mess. ;)